# an unusual List Comprehensions execution order

Tags: python, list

I come across a list comprehension that is not quite the same as usual. So I am confused about the list-compresion execution order.

```
import re

folders = ['train_frames001', 'train_masks002', 
'val_frames003','val_masks004', 'test_frames005', 'test_masks006']

folders.sort(key=lambda var:[int(x) if x.isdigit() else x 
                    for x in re.findall(r'[^0-9]|[0-9]+', var)])


print(folders)
#Whether the list compresion part means
#for x in re.findall(r'[^0-9]|[0-9]+', var):
#  if x.isdigit():
#    int(x)
#  else:
#    x
```

I did't find related samples and docs.

Comment: *"not quite the same as usual"* – what execution order did you expect?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I think OP referes that `if-else` comes before `for` and only `if` comes after `for` in `list-comprehension`.

Comment: You might be consued by the ternary operator there (... if ... else ...), but that's just a normal expression like any other. The list comprehension itself is in the normal order, and does not have an own `if`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confused between order of `if-else`.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

If you want simply square of each number

```
b = [i**2 for i in a]
# [1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64]
```

If you want even numbers (`if` statement in `list-comprehension`)

```
c = [i for i in a if i%2==0]
# [2,4,6,8]
```

If you want to square only even numbers(`if-else` statement `ternary operator`)

```
c = [i**2 if i%2==0 else i for i in a]
# [1,4,3,16,5,36,7,64]
```

Answer (score 0):

I run the code, and get `['test_frames005', 'test_masks006', 'train_frames001', 'train_masks002', 'val_frames003', 'val_masks004']`, I think the result is right.

If you want get result like `['train_frames001', 'train_masks002', 'val_frames003', 'val_masks004', 'test_frames005', 'test_masks006']`, which sorted by the end number. Maybe you should change your code like below.

```
import re

folders = ['train_frames001', 'train_masks002',
           'val_frames003', 'val_masks004', 'test_frames005', 'test_masks006']

folders.sort(key=lambda var: [int(x)
                              for x in re.findall(r'[^0-9]|[0-9]+', var) if x.isdigit()])

print(folders)
```

Comment: OP is asking about order of list-comprehension